# cannot see the pushed branch using `git branch -r`

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I cloned a git repository from **github**, created a new branch `branch1`, commited some changes in it, then pushed the new branch into a remote **gitlab** repository. Then created another branch from `branch1` named `branch2`, and pushed to remote gitlab repo. Now, when I use `git branch -r` I only see `branch1`. But if I clone the remote gitlab repository in another folder I can see both branches.

I also observed when I pushed for the first time into the remote repository, only `branch1` was pushed, but not `master` branch for example.

One more observation, I can see `branch2` online in my gitlab account.

I am really confused why this happens. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your configuration, `git push` without specifying a branch can be interpreted in different ways, be it a global push for all branches, or a narrow push of the currently checked out branch, among others.

Check your config with `git config -l` for the `push.default` entry. You can choose between possible modes, take a look at [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault). (`simple` is the default since git 2.0, but before that it was `matching`)

To set it, just do `git config --global push.default <yourPickedMode>`

Also, remember that `git branch -r` does *not* check remote branches directly but local refs for them. Be sure to `git fetch` beforehand to get them in sync with your distant repo if needed)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're setting the remote-tracking for your branches when you push so this is the expected behavior. See the help for `git branch -r`;

> **-r**
>   **--remotes**
>
> List or delete (if used with -d) the remote-tracking branches.

Try pushing with `git push -u` which sets the upstream tracking branch. Try `git branch --all` to see all the branches.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer thanks to the above answers. The problem was that I didn't specify the `remote` for `push`/`fetch` to/from the new gitlab repo. When I `fetch`ed, the data from the previous github repo were downloaded. First, I have to `add` a `remote` or replace the current `origin` by setting URL:
`git remote add new_remote <URL/remote_repo>`

Then I can fetch to update:
`git fetch new_remote`

Then checkout a branch in the `new_remote`:
`git checkout new_branch`